# ARANGODB. Can I use LOWER() in PHRASE search?

Tags: arangodb

I know when we use the filter function, we could apply a LOWER()/UPPER() function to match our search criterion.

```
FOR d IN doc
FILTER LOWER(d.category) == "abc"
LIMIT 10
RETURN d
```

However, what if I use PHRASE() in arangosearch?
I write code like this, but I get error messages.

```
FOR d IN vKBS
SEARCH ANALYZER(MIN_MATCH(
    PHRASE(LOWER(d["category"]), 'abc'),
    PHRASE(LOWER(d["name"]), 'abc'),
, 1), 'text_en')
SORT BM25(d)
LIMIT 50
RETURN d
```

How can I ignore case sensitivity in arangosearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the analyzer option. the en_text analyzer should already lower the case if not you can create another analyzer of type text

You can check the analyzers docs here

https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/arangosearch-analyzers.html#text